# How to show that $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\quad |\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|y|}|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}\leq\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\quad  |\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|y|}|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}\leq\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}$.

i tired

we want to prove for all  $x,y\in \mathbb{R}\quad  |\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|y|}|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}\leq\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}$.

we can start to show that   $\sqrt{|x-y|}\leq\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}$.

i don't know if i let $a=|x|,b=|y|$ or start by this way

we've :$\sqrt{|x-y|}\leq\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|} \Longleftrightarrow  \sqrt{|x-y|}^{2}\leq\left(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}\right)^{2} \Longleftrightarrow |x-y|\leq |x|+2\sqrt{|xy|}+|y| $

i'm stuck

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Since $|x-y|\leq|x|+|y|\leq|x|+2\sqrt{|xy|}+|y|$ (triangle inequality) it follows by taking the square root on both sides that $\sqrt{|x-y|}\leq\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}$.

From the reverse triangle inequality we have that $\Big||x|-|y|\Big|\leq|x-y|$. Let $|x|\geq|y|$. Then $|x|-2\sqrt{|x||y|}+|y|\leq|x|-2|y|+|y|=|x|-|y|=\Big||x|-|y|\Big|\leq|x-y|$. Taking square roots on both sides and taking in account that everything is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ yields the desired result.